# How to make plots for data exploration in sparkling waters h2oflow UI?

Tags: scala, data-visualization, sparkling-water

I am trying to explore a sample dataset by visualizing the data using plots like Box plots, scatter plots, histograms, etc.

Unfortunately, I not able to find any commands even in the H2o documentation on how to print or show plots of data.

Is there any recommended library to use?

Answer (score 0):

To make custom plots you should use H2O from R (with ggplot2) or Python (with matplotlib).